# Problems Creating User Preferences File

Tags: java, android, settings, android-preferences

I'm currently creating an android app, in which you can train maths. Today i wanted to add a Settings page so i followed the guide from the official android docs: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/components/settings

Now I've come to a problem. I have created a settings fragment:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Number Range">

    </PreferenceCategory>
    <EditTextPreference
        android:defaultValue="1"
        android:key="ET_xmin"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:title="Minimum X" />
    <EditTextPreference
        android:defaultValue="15"
        android:key="ET_xmax"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:title="Maximum X" />
    <EditTextPreference
        android:defaultValue="1"
        android:key="ET_ymin"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:title="Minimum Y" />
    <EditTextPreference
        android:defaultValue="15"
        android:key="ET_ymax"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:title="Maximum Y" />
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Math Actions">

    </PreferenceCategory>
    <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        android:id="@+id/SPC_multiply"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:defaultValue="true"
        app:key="doMultiply"
        app:title="Multiply" />

    <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        android:id="@+id/SPC_divide"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:defaultValue="false"
        app:key="doDivide"
        app:title="Divide" />
    <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        android:id="@+id/SPC_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:defaultValue="false"
        app:key="doAdd"
        app:title="Add" />
    <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        android:id="@+id/SPC_subtract"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:defaultValue="false"
        app:key="doSubtract"
        app:title="Subtract" />
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Other">

    </PreferenceCategory>
    <Preference
        app:key="feedback"
        app:title="Send feedback"
        app:summary="Report technical issues or suggest new features"/>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

[image of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rjvv7.png)

then I created a SettingsActivity.java like I was told in the guide.

```java
package com.example.testapp1;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;

public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.settings_container, new MySettingsFragment())
                .commit();

    }
}
```

and also a MySettingsFragment.java

```java
package com.example.testapp1;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;

public class MySettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey);
    }
}
```

Ive also created an empty preferences.xml file.

Now im stuck.
I don't know what to write into the preferences.xml file so that i can access it, and also I dont know how to implement settings_container. (it doesn't exist)

Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I will share my Setting Fragment. my Code will help you to write yours.
But DON'T PUT THE KEYS in string XML resources, I did this just development stage.

```
class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat(),
    SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
    private val dataHandler: DataHandler by lazy {
        MyApp.instance.dataHandler
    }
    private val uploadKey = MyApp.instance.resources.getString(R.string.upload_key)
    private val uploadUrlKey = MyApp.instance.resources.getString(R.string.upload_url_key)
    private val uploadUrlPathKey = MyApp.instance.resources.getString(R.string.upload_url_path_key)
    private val usernameKey = MyApp.instance.resources.getString(R.string.username_key)
    private val loggedEnabledKey = MyApp.instance.resources.getString(R.string.logged_enabled_key)
    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey)
        val edit_Pref = preferenceScreen.findPreference<EditTextPreference>(uploadUrlKey)
        edit_Pref?.setOnPreferenceChangeListener { preference, newValue ->
            if ((newValue as String).last() == '/') true
            else {
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Url should end with /", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                false
            }
        }
        }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        preferenceScreen.sharedPreferences?.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this)
    }

    override fun onSharedPreferenceChanged(sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences?, key: String?) {
        when (key) {
            uploadKey -> {
                val usingMobileData = (sharedPreferences?.getString(uploadKey, "false") == "true")

                dataHandler.uploadInternetPermissionChanged(usingMobileData)
            }
            uploadUrlKey -> {
                val url = sharedPreferences?.getString(uploadUrlKey, "") ?: ""
                dataHandler.uploadUrlChanged(url)
            }
            uploadUrlPathKey -> {
                val path = sharedPreferences?.getString(uploadUrlPathKey, "") ?: ""
                dataHandler.uploadUrlPathChanged(path)
            }

            usernameKey -> {
                val username = sharedPreferences?.getString(usernameKey, "") ?: ""
                dataHandler.uploadUsernameChanged(username)
            }
            loggedEnabledKey -> {
                val enable = sharedPreferences?.getBoolean(loggedEnabledKey, false) ?: false
                if (enable) {
                    actionOnService(Actions.START)
                } else {
                    actionOnService(Actions.STOP)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun actionOnService(action: Actions) {
        with(MyApp.instance.applicationContext) {
            if (getServiceState(this) == ServiceState.STOPPED && action == Actions.STOP)
                return
            Intent(this, TimeStudioService::class.java).also {
                it.action = action.name
                startForegroundService(this, it)
            }
        }
    }
}
```